# how to update materialize switch element while ajax returns error?

Tags: jquery, materialize

how to update switch status? this ajax error not update the materialize switch in my code.

```
$(document).on('change','.setStatus',function(){    
    if($(this).prop('checked')==true){
        var activeStatus=1;     
    }else{
        var activeStatus=0;     
    }

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'service.php',
    data:{'status':activeStatus,'userId':userId},
    success:function(data){
    },          
    error:function(){
        if(activeStatus==1){
            $(this).prop('checked',false);      // but this not update.                         
        }else{
            $(this).prop('checked',true);   // but this not update.                     
        }
    }               
   });
});
```

Comment: This woked for you???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) doesn't work inside callbacks. So store $(this) in variable to update. Like

```
$(document).on('change','.setStatus',function(){    
    var this1 = $(this);
    if(this1.prop('checked')==true){
        var activeStatus=1;     
    }else{
        var activeStatus=0;     
    }

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'service.php',
    data:{'status':activeStatus,'userId':userId},
    success:function(data){
    },          
    error:function(){
        if(activeStatus==1){
            this1.prop('checked',false);      // this will update.                         
        }else{
            this1.prop('checked',true);   // this will update.                     
        }
    }               
   });
});
```

Or you can use context variable.. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call. So inside callback this will refer to current context. You can do like

```
$(document).on('change','.setStatus',function(){    
    if($(this).prop('checked')==true){
        var activeStatus=1;     
    }else{
        var activeStatus=0;     
    }

    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'service.php',
    context: $(this),
    data:{'status':activeStatus,'userId':userId},
    success:function(data){
    },          
    error:function(){
        if(activeStatus==1){
            $(this).prop('checked',false);      //  this will update.                         
        }else{
            $(this).prop('checked',true);   //  this will update.                     
        }
    }               
   });
});
```

You can read more about context [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your $(this) inside the error callback is no longer referring to the switch element. You can store the switch element in a variable and then use that variable to change the prop. Maybe something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.setStatus', function () {
    var activeStatus = 0;
    var $switch = $(this);

    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        activeStatus = 1;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'service.php',
        data: {'status': activeStatus, 'userId': userId},
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function () {
            if (activeStatus == 1) {
                $switch.prop('checked', false);      // but this not update.                         
            } else {
                $switch.prop('checked', true);   // but this not update.                     
            }
        }
    });
});
```